# Defining JupyterHub Kubernetes resources for each user

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I was following the [zero to jupyterhub](http://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-resources.html) tutorial on spawning a kubernetes cluster for managing Jupter Notebook, and it's not clear how to specify resources for a specific user.

On our current deployment, each user has an AWS machine associated with the Jupyter Notebook, and this can be customized in a per-user basis. How can I do the same thing using JupyterHub?